# How can I merge a record on sync using Zumero rather than adding it?

Tags: sql-server, merge, zumero

I show my users a list of items to choose from and they pick an item to work with. If the store is disconnected, the item they need might not be there, so I offer the ability to enter an identifier of the item and then create a new local, object for them to work with.

When it comes time to sync, I don't want this new row to be automatically created in the database, I want a way to intercept the merge and check to see if such a record already exists, and if so, use that as the desired row, otherwise insert.

Is this possible, and how should it be implemented?